# (MS FoxPro) - Making variable duplicates/appending records

Tags: arrays, duplicates, append, row, foxpro

I need to write a program which would duplicate some rows, according to a number provided in one of the data fields.

Each row contains a name/address data && a number, that number tells how many times this row has to be copied, as per example below (4 being THIS number)

Mr A Simpson, Sunshine Street 20490, New York, 4
*!* so, this record requires another 3 duplicates, to make 4 in total, as below
Mr A Simpson, Sunshine Street 20490, New York, 4
Mr A Simpson, Sunshine Street 20490, New York, 4
Mr A Simpson, Sunshine Street 20490, New York, 4

Program would either append new records at bottom of the table, then fill them with relevant data (and sort it so the duplicates are one after another) or just make a duplicate after each line if possible. I suppose this have be something to do the Arrays, which I'm not familiar with at all and it's already taking me hours to get through.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Does the data needing duplicated get appended to the same table? If so, there are a couple of techniques to try.

1: Make sure you are on the row needing duplicated, then:

```
SCATTER MEMVAR    &&Save fields to memory varibles of the same name
APPEND BLANK      &&Adds a blank record to the end of the current table
GATHER MEMVAR     &&Adds the memory variables values to the appropiate columns
```

2: Using INSERT Command

```
SCATTER MEMVAR    &&Save fields to memory varibles of the same name
INSERT INTO myTableName FROM MEMVAR   &&Adds a record and populates the columns
```

As far as getting the number of duplicates you need, such as 4 from your example, you could perform a loop on the filtered table such as:

```
&&Get records that need dups processed. Add WHERE condition if needed.
SELECT * FROM myTableName INTO CURSOR myTemp  
SELECT myTemp
SCAN
    SCATTER MEMVAR
    FOR i = 1 TO m.CountFieldName
       INSERT INTO myTableName FROM MEMVAR
    ENDFOR
ENDSCAN
```

I haven't tested the code but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Just one caution here. If you're inserting into the same table, then you need to make sure your loop stops once you get past all the original records, or you'll run forever.

Answer (score 0):

As Tamar mentioned in above comment, appending into the same table could cause a recursive result.  You might consider taking your results into an "alternate" work area from your original table to do whatever final action on (printing or whatever), then close when done.  This way, the original remains intact with a single entry.

That said, and based on repetition, I would create a temporary cursor with a record (or more) to SIMULATE a result set... ie: 1 has 1 record, 2 has 2, 5 has 5...

```
create cursor C_TempNumbers ( int numMatch )
index on numMatch tag numMatch
for i = 1 to 10
   for j = 1 to i
      insert into C_TempNumbers ( numMatch ) values ( i )
   endfor
endfor
```

So Now, I have a table and index with records like

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

etc..

Now, I would just query from your original table joined to this cursor based on the numMatch.  If only 1, it will find 1 record, return 1 row.  If 4 is the number, it will be returned 4 times.  The nice thing... if you have 20 entries with a 4, 30 with a 3, etc... they will still get their proper count.

```
select YT.*; 
   from YourOriginalTable YT ;
      join C_TempNumbers ;
         on YT.YourNumberColumn = C_TempNumbers.numMatch; 
   into cursor C_FinalResult readwrite
```

Done... your final table ready to go, and your original intact without putting all the duplicates in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both, we (my and my colleague) have dealt with this issue bit differently, I would say in a simpler way as we're far from being experts.. The only issue I have now, we need to deal with not one but TWO of these fields (called hopa_gold or hwc_red below). So for instance, if one reads '2' and the other '3' we need to produce 1 duplicate of first one (to make two in total) and two of the other one (so it would produce three of them in total). This doesn't happen too often, so I assume we'll do those 'by hand' if necessary. Our (very simple!) code is below. The first line changes field to numer, otherwise it wasn't working. Please let me know what you think. Cheers

```
ALTER table input alter hopa_gold n(10)
ALTER table input alter hwc_red n(10)
COUNT TO lastrec
Initval = 1
Varname = 1
trec = 1
GO top
replace ALL tnum WITH hopa_gold+hwc_red
GO top
FOR trec = 1 TO lastrec
    FOR VarName = Initval TO (tnum-1)  

      SCATTER MEMVAR 
      APPEND BLANK
      GATHER MEMVAR 

    ENDFOR
    GOTO trec + 1

ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field with the number of required copies is 'numcopies' and you have a unique row identifier called 'id'...

```
select * from mytable where .f. into cursor curTemp readwrite
select mytable
scan for numcopies > 0
    scatter name currentrow fields except id      
    for lnCount = 1 to currentrow.copies
        currentrow.id = GetNextId()
        insert into curTemp from name currentrow
    endfor
endscan
select mytable
append from dbf('curtemp')
use in select('curtemp')
```

In terms of getting the id values for the new rows, either you will have to calculate yourself or if the field is type autoinc then just don't include it and it will get handled automatically by the DBC.